# Vpn network set up

Tags: windows, windows-vista

I have recently set up a vpn which looks like it's working! But slightly confused as when I open my network sharing center it shows I'm not connected to internet 
My comp>>>>>multiple networks then shows a red x between multiple networks and internet. When I click on show my network map it shows I am connected 
My comp>>>my ISP>>>>Internet (doesn't show multiple networks) 
My vpn is connected and shows as Unidentified connection but won't let me see the network map for it!

I've done a dns leak test and IP address checks and all that stuff and everything looks fine but can't help wondering about the above issues!
I am a total novice so take that in to consideration when answering please! 
Thankyou happy new year :-)

Comment: The network is unidentified so this is probably the cause. Can you change the type? Can you ping devices on the other end of the VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the network mapping... In Windows Vista, Microsoft tried to make this a big feature to make home networking a lot simpler, and it was further improved in Windows 7 with the addition of Homegroup and other features.... and whilst they kept the service in Windows 8, the GUI was removed and the feature is pretty much not used any more.

To read more about it - [click here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_Layer_Topology_Discovery).

It looks nice, but, it isn't very informative and it certainly isn't complete for all scenarios, VPN being one of them.